# How fast will it converge to equilibrium？

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, equidistribution

$\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, given $\varepsilon>0 \quad \lambda>0$.

given $n_{1}, \cdots, n_{k} \in N^{*}$ satisfied  $(1-\varepsilon) \lambda<n_{1}<\cdots<n_{k}<(1+\varepsilon)\lambda$, then

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\#\left\{\left(i_{1},...,i_{k}\right) \mid i_{1}+\cdots_{k}=n, \ i_{j} \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \cup\{0\}\right.\}} \sum_{i_1+\cdots+i_{k}=n}\left\{n_{1}^{i_{1}}... n_{k}^{i k} \alpha\right\}= \frac{1}{2} 
 \quad \quad (*)$

Where $\{\alpha\}$ is the decimal part of $\alpha$, then how can we estimate the speed of LHS$(*)$ convergent to $\frac{1}{2}$ for a generic $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$? this speed can depend on $\lambda, \epsilon$.